# Log the selected value from radio button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a dropdown list with radio buttons where you can select several different styles for the web page.

I first want to try to `console.log` whenever I select a different color. Every time I select a different color, it still logs the color black.

This is my html code:

```
<form>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="black" checked="checked" onclick="styleChange()"/>Black</label>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="red" onclick="styleChange()">Red</label>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="green" onclick="styleChange()">Green</label>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="blue" onclick="styleChange()">Blue</label>
</form>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
function styleChange() {
   if (document.getElementById("black").selected = true) {
       console.log("Color selected: Black")
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("red").selected = true) {
       console.log("Color selected: Red")
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("green").selected = true) {
       console.log("Color selected: Green")
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("blue").selected = true) {
       console.log("Color selected: Blue")
   }
}
```

Comment: As long as you are using `onclick` you might as well use `onclick="styleChange('red`)"' (for example).
And use `==` for comparison, not `=` (assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change selected to checked and don't use single equal in if condition, it should be double equal. code below.

```
function styleChange() {
  
   if (document.getElementById("black").checked) {
       console.log("Color selected: Black")
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("red").checked) {
       console.log("Color selected: Red")
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("green").checked) {
       console.log("Color selected: Green")
   }
   else if (document.getElementById("blue").checked) {
       console.log("Color selected: Blue")
   }
}
```

demo https://jsbin.com/giberegora/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thank you, I thought I already tried this, but I must've made a small mistake. The jsbin was really helpfull as well!

Answer (score 1):

You could add onChange event listener to every radio button and call a method whenever the onChange event occurs.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(item => {
       item.addEventListener("change", () => {
          console.log(item.id)
       })
})
```

```html
<form>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="black" checked="checked"/>Black</label>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="red">Red</label>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="green">Green</label>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" id="blue">Blue</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer! If I were to only log the color, I would've used this. But since I want to style certain ID's, I don't think I can use yours.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use jquery it easy to use and more productive as compared to javascript code and one more thing I change "id" to "value" for checking which radio button is selected please check the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    <label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" value="black" onclick="styleChange()"/>Black</label>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" value="red" onclick="styleChange()">Red</label>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" value="green" onclick="styleChange()">Green</label>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="styleColor" value="blue" onclick="styleChange()">Blue</label>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
function styleChange(){
      alert($("input[name='styleColor']:checked").val());
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I usually would use jquery, but since I'm working with ASP.NET MVC, I don't really know how to use jquery and since it won't be a public website and I'll only use small javascript things, I didn't really think about using jquery.

Comment: it is very easy and improves the performance of your application but for the first time maybe it will take some time but for the long run, it will give you good benefits https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_bundling.htm